# parsing jps output into array

Tags: bash, process

I'm using jps in a bash shell to find all running java processes. I want to be able to use the list of PIDs that is output by jps. I can successfully print them to the screen using

```
jps | awk '{print $1}'
```

but I expect more than one process to be running and I would like to put them in an array. I found another example where they used

```
awk '{arr[$1]}'
```

because the output that they wanted in the array was a single column. This is similar to the column of PIDs that I want put into an array.

Is it possible to pipe them into an array? I'm having trouble getting the index of the array to change when needed. Is there a better way to do this?

Any guidance would be warmly received.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your first example, you should be able to capture all process IDs in a bash array using

```
pids=( $(jps | awk '{print $1}') )
```

Once in the array, they can be iterated over:

```
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
     echo $pid
done
```

or accessed individually

```
echo "${pids[0]}"
echo "${pids[1]}"
```

The total number stored in the array is found with `${#pids[@]}`.

Comment: Once I have them in a list, how would I separate them? It gives me 1111 2222 when I ask for a single element. I've been reading some things about `tr` and `sed` but I'm not sure how to apply that to splitting the two pids apart. Most the examples I have seen are getting rid of delimiters and new line.

Answer (score 0):

use xargs:

ps aux | grep -ie java | awk '{print $2}' | xargs echo